# why is the hours missing on time transformation?

Tags: ruby

The time stamp is missing on the parsing. What needs to be done to ensure that the timestamp is also there?

```
 irb(main):060:0> dt= Date.parse "2021-08-06T15:00:00-04:00"
    => #<Date: 2021-08-06 ((2459433j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
    irb(main):061:0> dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L")
    => "2021-08-06 00:00:00.000"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `DateTime`:

```
require 'date'

dt = DateTime.parse("2021-08-06T15:00:00+04:00")
result = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L")
puts result
```

Yielding `2021-08-06 15:00:00.000`.

Comment: `Time` would work as well, I think. `DateTime` is part of the standard libraries and `Time` part of the core libraries. (Okay, actually I'm just commenting this because I found a super fascinating [thing](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#class-DateTime-label-When+should+you+use+DateTime+and+when+should+you+use+Time-3F) in the docs about when to choose `Time` and when to choose `DateTime`...)

Comment: @Josien - Thank you so much for the reference. A fine addition to my collection of historical oddities, but with a small hint of Ruby.